# Get access to the function from different scope - native js

Tags: javascript, scope

What I supposted to do to get access to a function from different scope. I want to return invoked function from different scope.

Code:

```
function a (language) {
  if(language === 'pl'){
    return 'it works';
  } else {
    return 'not working';
  }
}

function b (language) {
  function downloadAjax (lang) {

    //How I can get access to a function?
    return a(language);  
  }
  downloadAjax(language);
}


//main function
function c () {
  console.log(b('pl'));
}

c();
```

Talking about **b function which supposted to return invoked a function**. Right now it's logging undefinied.

Tried with:

```
//global scope
var self = this;
//function scope
return this.a(language)

//binding this
return a.call(this, language)
```

but still doesn't work.

Comment: `supposted to return` - well, function b doesn't return anything ... perhaps if you `return downloadAjax(language);` then it will `return` something

Comment: Also, is `downloadAjax` asynchronous? Because regardless of whether you return something from `b`, your result still might not be what you're expecting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are logging the return value of `b` but the `b` function **has no `return` statement**.

If you want to return the result of `downloadAjax(language)` from `b` then you need to do so explicitly: `return downloadAjax(language)`.

Answer (score 2):

What you have works, function c's has access to all of those function when it looks in the global scope.  You are missing an explicit return from your second function.

```
function b (language) {
  function downloadAjax (lang) {

    //How I can get access to a function?
    return a(language);  
  }

  // return missed here
  return downloadAjax(language);
}
```